# mapbox direction or optimization api (how to avoid tolls/bridges/etc)

Tags: leaflet, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I am using mapbox and leaflet and leaflet plugin.

I have a very simple question. I'd like to have the option to avoid tolls/bridges/etc by passing the specific option. Is this possible ? I've seen that for mapbox swift , it's possible, but i don't see anything mapbox api has something like this for Directions/Optimization API.

Any idea on how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You can pass `exclude=toll` to the API call to avoid tolls.

[Documentation](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/navigation/#retrieve-directions)

Comment: yes, but if you look at optimization api, i can't pass things like that. How do I do that for optimization api?

Comment: According to the documentation, it looks like that's not supported.